# How Do I Set AutoLayout on iPhone SE & 5S?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

So I have auto layout working for all devices except iphone SE ...Can someone show me how to setup constraints specifically just for that phone...?

This is how the layout looks on iPhone 8 wC wR size class (This is what I want it to look like):

[image]

This is how the layout looks like on iPhone SE also wC wR size class:

[image]

These are the constraints I have on both iPhones (8 & SE)...the bottom space constraint is the space between the logo and the 00 label which is centered horizontally and vertically...That constraint for the 00 label must remain unchanged in my case.

Logo constraint

[image]

Title Constraint

[image]

00 Label Constraint

[image]

min constraint

[image]

continue button constraint

[image]

**How can I adjust the constraints for the iPhone SE to look like the iPhone 8??**

Comment: Add more details for your layout design and constraints.

Comment: @PratikSodha Done

Comment: How are you setting these autolayout constraints? In storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @Munib in storyboard...I added variations between wC and hR (iphone) vs wR and hR (iPad)..those variations work fine...but for some reason on the iphone SE and iphone 5S, the constraints are off

Comment: @YungGoat Here problem is not with size classes... Problem is your constraints. Please refer link for size classes. -https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

Comment: I think in your case your issues with you center **00 min** label have `centrally vertical` constraint with `view` so, the layout issues is their.

Comment: Show your constraints code please.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri done

Comment: I believe you need to post the constraints for everything on the screen and tell us which one is for which element especially for the label on the top.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri done

Comment: You have a lot of conflicting constraints. You need to remove bottom and top constraints for all labels and just set one of them. Preferably the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can add specific constraints for determinate devices.

Choose a constraint and click on plus icon(is on the left side of label "Constant") and then you can select a specific device for set it a variation of the constraint.

In this case, for iPhone SE and iPhone 5s you should select width: Compact, height: Regular, Gamut: Any

[Click on plus icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y7JN.png)
[You can set it a specific constraint for that device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv8d6.png)